# 215. Kth Largest Element in an Array C++ Solution Not Working

Tags: c++

Given an integer array nums and an integer k, return the kth largest element in the array.

Note that it is the kth largest element in the sorted order, not the kth distinct element.

Example 1:

Input: nums = [3,2,1,5,6,4], k = 2
Output: 5

My Solution Is Below and I do not understand why it is not working. Maybe I am reading the question wrong? Can someone please explain.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int findKthLargest(vector<int>& nums, int k) {
        sort(nums.begin(), nums.end() );
        nums.erase(unique(nums.begin(), nums.end() ), nums.end() );
        
        return nums.size() - k;
        
    }
};
```

Comment: How should `nums.size() - k` ever result in a value that is stored in `nums`?

Comment: @t.niese through a 19th dimension transform.

Comment: @t.niese For instance If I have a vector called nums and it holds [1,2,3,4] and I do nums.size() - 1 wouldn't that give me 4? and then If I do nums.size() - 2 wouldn't that give me 3?

Comment: The result of `nums.size() - n` completely independent of the values that are stored in `nums`, it only depends one its size (number of elements stored in it). The size of `[1,2,3,4]` is `4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go through your function, with your example

> Input: nums = [3,2,1,5,6,4], k = 2 Output: 5

1. You do sort in ascending order `std::sort(iterator begin, iterator end)`. That.s good.
   After that, you have **sorted vector**: *1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6*

Edit://
I haven't noticed it: (so second point is correct now).

> Note that it is the kth largest element in the sorted order, not the kth distinct element.

So you should erease duplicates.

2. You erease duplicate value. After that, you have **sorted vector without duplicates**: *1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6* (same as before, cos all values are distinct). That's not good. Leave duplicates as you said in post.
3. You return int. But what's stored in this int? `num.size() - k`.
   What number is `num.size()`? *6*, because vector has six elements. K = 2 (from input). So, result is 4. You return *int* with value *4*. You don't return any element from vector or sth like. You return size of vector minus const (parameter). But value *4* is good, but you have to do with it something more.

Think about your return. Hope it's help.

PS. Don't use namespace std. Always go with `std::sort` etc.

Comment: Oh okay! So basicially vec.size() - k would be the size of the array minus a certain number oh okay got it. That did help thanks!

Comment: Yes, result is an index of vector element. If my answer help, Mark  it as answered, please :)

Comment: There ya go :D can you upvote my post too.